# Is the Monte Carlo integration method(s) actually a viable way to accurately integrate functions?

Tags: calculus, probability, numerical-methods, monte-carlo, approximate-integration

Recently, I was playing around with some Monte Carlo simulations using Python to evaluate integrals of functions such as f(x) = x(1-x)sin²[200x(1-x)].

I am aware that Monte Carlo integration methods are not particularly accurate (because they are non-deterministic), but I was wondering: do they actually get used in applications?

Perhaps scientists (as in physicists, chemists...etc.) use it to approximate integrals that they otherwise cannot approximate any better.

Comment: Monte Carlo is used constantly...it's tremendously important as a numerical technique.  And yes, it has problems, as with any numerical method. It works much better when you have some controls in place (typically, "similar" problems for which a closed form, or good analytic approximation, is available).

Comment: I see. For fun, I approximated pi using the function f(x) = sqrt(1 - x^2), since analytically it equals to pi/4. Got a relatively reasonable approximation, which is quite nice...

Comment: You can easily experiment in python with the numeric integration of a function of, say, four or even more variables. This can be astonishingly slow. Monte Carlo simulation can be much quicker.

Comment: Look up "low-discrepancy" or quasi-random sequences. They fill the space more evenly and converge a little less glacially when used in MC integration.